# Windows application developed using VS2012 is not running in windows XP SP3

Tags: c#, .net

I have developed an windows application in Visual Studio 2012 with .NET framework 4. But when i tried to install my application in Windows XP SP3 it shows that the .exe is not a valid win32 application. Please help me to solve.

Comment: Do you have the .Net framework installed on that machine? Also, is the application compiled targeting x86 or 64?

Comment: The OS you are using to develop is that 32bit or 64bit? It is not a show stopper, you will just need to change your target build architecture is there is a difference.

Comment: Are you *certain* that you are targeting version 4.0 of the .NET Framework? Versions 4.5 and 4.6 will *not* work on Windows XP.

Comment: This happens when you target 4.5 or higher.   .NET compiler take advantage of those framework versions not being available on XP and they change the target Windows version, indicating that Vista or higher is required.  Pretty important.  Such a program will keel over on XP with this message.  Could be a DLL as well.

Comment: I am using windows 7 32 Bit OS and tried to install in windows XP SP3 32 Bit system

Comment: I have targeted my exe for .Net framework 4.0

Answer (score 1):

This could be one of two, or both, issues. First, ensure that you have the .Net Framework installed on that machine. Second, make sure the application is compiled targeting x86 platform. Most likely, it is the the second issue.

Comment: In addition, VS2012 Update2 migjt be required.

Comment: Framework is installed on that machine. I am using VS2012 Update5.